# Stop or prevent hacker overwhelm the web server

Tags: symfony, security

I have an ecommerce site running on php Symfony2. Someone is sending random GET and POST requests with random routes. This crashes my server.

How do I stop or prevent this? Is there a name for this kind of hacking?

Here is my production log.

`[2018-04-07 18:18:28] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "HEAD /phpmyadmin/"" at /var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 176 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"HEAD /phpmyadmin/\" at /var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php:176, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0): No routes found for \"/phpmyadmin/\". at /var/www/app/cache/prod/classes.php:2427)"} []
[2018-04-07 18:18:30] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "HEAD /dbadmin/"" at /var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 176 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"HEAD /dbadmin/\" at /var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php:176, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0): No routes found for \"/dbadmin/\". at /var/www/app/cache/prod/classes.php:2427)"} []
[2018-04-07 18:18:31] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "HEAD /db/"" at /var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 176 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"HEAD /db/\" at /var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php:176, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0): No routes found for \"/db/\". at /var/www/app/cache/prod/classes.php:2427)"} []
[2018-04-07 21:53:39] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "POST /wls-wsat/CoordinatorPortType"" at /var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 176 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"POST /wls-wsat/CoordinatorPortType\" at /var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php:176, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0): No routes found for \"/wls-wsat/CoordinatorPortType\". at /var/www/app/cache/prod/classes.php:2427)"} []
[2018-04-08 03:04:11] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /'http://ewhale.co/"" at /var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 176 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET /'http://ewhale.co/\" at /var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php:176, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0): No routes found for \"/'http://ewhale.co/\". at /var/www/app/cache/prod/classes.php:2427)"} []
[2018-04-08 06:17:36] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /index.action"" at /var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 176 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET /index.action\" at /var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php:176, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0): No routes found for \"/index.action\". at /var/www/app/cache/prod/classes.php:2427)"} []
[2018-04-08 06:20:02] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /_asterisk/"" at /var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 176 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET /_asterisk/\" at /var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php:176, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0): No routes found for \"/_asterisk/\". at /var/www/app/cache/prod/classes.php:2427)"} []
[2018-04-08 08:35:49] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "POST /autodiscover/autodiscover.xml"" at /var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 176 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"POST /autodiscover/autodiscover.xml\" at /var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php:176, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0): No routes found for \"/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml\". at /var/www/app/cache/prod/classes.php:2427)"} []
[2018-04-08 08:35:49] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "POST /autodiscover/autodiscover.xml"" at /var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 176 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"POST /autodiscover/autodiscover.xml\" at /var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php:176, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0): No routes found for \"/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml\". at /var/www/app/cache/prod/classes.php:2427)"} []
[2018-04-08 08:35:49] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /.well-known/autoconfig/mail/config-v1.1.xml" (from "http://ewhale.co/.well-known/autoconfig/mail/config-v1.1.xml")" at /var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 176 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET /.well-known/autoconfig/mail/config-v1.1.xml\" (from \"http://ewhale.co/.well-known/autoconfig/mail/config-v1.1.xml\") at /var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php:176, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0): No routes found for \"/.well-known/autoconfig/mail/config-v1.1.xml\". at /var/www/app/cache/prod/classes.php:2427)"} []
[2018-04-08 08:35:59] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "POST /autodiscover/autodiscover.xml"" at /var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 176 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"POST /autodiscover/autodiscover.xml\" at /var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php:176, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0): No routes found for \"/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml\". at /var/www/app/cache/prod/classes.php:2427)"} []`

Comment: Search for Denial-of-Service (DoS) attack. One way to prevent this type of attacks in a business application is to use a loadbalancer with DoS protection.

Comment: I am using AWS ELB. My understanding is AWS Shield is activated for DoS attack. Is there any more I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i can understand, from the logs you provide, i can tell you:

- There is nothing to worry about, unless you expose tools like
  phpmyadmin on common endpoints, such as abc.com/phpmyadmin
- You can't prevent those.

Simply you can't. Because they are random. In these days, even good amount of DoS request can be identified and dropped with cloud solutions like cloudflare. (because DoS requests have somewhat common pattern)

But with this type of random attacks, you have no choice. These requests come from bots. They try web sites randomly to find outdated common software (eg: wordpress, drupal) and inject malicious code if they can.